# Flutter Sign in problem My app crashes when i touch out of the sign in page

Tags: android, flutter

When i hit the sign in button ,there s no problem but if i touch out of the sign in page ,my app crashes with Platform exception.

And here's my google _ sign _ in codes. where is the problem

```
import 'package:competible_pc_builder/pages/splashscreen.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:google_sign_in/google_sign_in.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

Future<Object?> signInWithGoogle() async {
  try {
    // Trigger the authentication flow
    final GoogleSignInAccount? googleUser = await GoogleSignIn().signIn();

    // If user cancels the sign in process
    if(googleUser == null) return const SplashScreen();

    // Obtain the auth details from the request
    final GoogleSignInAuthentication googleAuth = await googleUser.authentication;

    // Create a new credential
    final credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(
      accessToken: googleAuth.accessToken,
      idToken: googleAuth.idToken,
    );

    // Once signed in, return the UserCredential
    return await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithCredential(credential);
  } catch (error) {
    if (error is PlatformException) {
      if (error.code == 'sign_in_canceled')  {

      } else {
        // Handle other exceptions here
      }
    }
    return null;
  }
}

Future<void> signOutWithGoogle() async {
  await FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut();
  await GoogleSignIn().signOut();
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.